# How to edit PDF properties in java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to edit existing properties or set new PDF properties such as author name, title, subject, etc. from a java application. Is there any way to do that? I have found the apache.pdfbox library but I don't know whether it will solve my issues or not?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Apache PDFBox has an [API to retrieve and update PDF metadata](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithmetadata.html).

Looking at the [example code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddMetadataFromDocInfo.java.htm), it does look like you have to get your hands dirty with XML a little, though.

Comment: Can you tell me then how to create the document object?

Comment: Thanx Thilo for your reply. I think those links will be enough for me.